# How to send software interrupts with a "cause code" in RISC-V?

Tags: riscv

I'm switching from ARM to RISC-V, so still learning.
My RISC-V chip has multiple cores. Core A/B/C needs to send software interrupts to core D for different reasons. But it looks like RISC-V has only one software interrupt ID, which is 3 in M mode (My firmware runs in M mode only). When Core D receives a software interrupt, how can it tell what the interrupt cause is?

With ARM GiC, there are 16 software interrupt IDs (0~15). So one core can send SGIs (Software Generated Interrupts) to another with different IDs to indicate the intention of the interrupt, such that the interrupted core can handle it accordingly.

Is there an alternative approach in RISC-V to handle this use case?

Thanks
-Oscar